# Why isn't blur() working on the full page when using css?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm getting [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBpo9.jpg) weird spaces with no blur.
It works perfect when I use F11 though.
Thanks.

```
body {
    background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

(I know it's ugly, just practising flexbox haha)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not supported in firefox .. You can use blur filter or overlay with transparent color like rgba(255, 255, 255, .8) instead

```css
div {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    
  background-image: url("https://imgs.search.brave.com/ceQErYxaonXPK0DI2EOfJfQMOk0THnBq2REOp5T4RCY/rs:fit:1200:1200:1/g:ce/aHR0cDovL3d3dy53/YWxscGFwZXJzMTMu/Y29tL3dwLWNvbnRl/bnQvdXBsb2Fkcy8y/MDE1LzEyL05hdHVy/ZS1MYWtlLUJsZWQu/LURlc2t0b3AtYmFj/a2dyb3VuZC1pbWFn/ZS5qcGc");
  
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```